# Swift 3 Firebase to MapKit

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit

I am looking to get data from a Firebase Database into a map. I have a good amount working but am stuck. This is all 100% code, no storyboards.

What I have below works. It will show all pins on a map but I am stuck at that point. I want to be able to tap each pin and get the data for that particular pin. When I do, using the code below I will print out "tap" and the array for MTA.

The data could be shown in a pin annotation/info window or in labels below the map in the View Controller. I am unsure of where to put the code/get it to work. I assume not in the for snap in snapshot but I cannot get the data out for each individual record/pin.

View did load for reference:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationItem.title = stop

        mapContainerView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(mapContainerView)


        setUpContorller()
        fetchTrip()
}
```

Function to get coordinates for map:

```
    func fetchTrip(){

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let tripsRef = ref.child("Trips").child(stop!)
    tripsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let tripSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot

            if let dict = tripSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                let lat = dict["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                let lng = dict["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                let MTA = dict["MTAStop"] as! String
                let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.08, longitudeDelta: 0.08))

                self.stopMTA.append(MTA)

                self.mapContainerView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                let pinCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = pinCoordinate
                self.mapContainerView.addAnnotation(annotation)

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Function to tap pin: (I know I need more.. not sure what, possibly a class to hold the data.)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    // do something
    print("tap")
    print(stopMTA)
}
```

Here is an example of the database from simulator testing.[image: Firebase Database Example]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MKPointAnnotation() will only place a pin on the map. You need to use a custom class to hold the annotation information and call it with initializers.

Original:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = pinCoordinate
self.mapContainerView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Working version:

```
let annotation = PinAnnotation(title: MTA, coordinate: pinCoordinate, info: MTA)
annotation.coordinate = pinCoordinate
self.mapContainerView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Also Need:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
}
```

and

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
}
```